# when use boilerplate react, The program does not automatically load when i change code

Tags: build, boilerplate

### Access URLs:

Localhost: http://localhost:3000

### LAN: http://192.168.1.149:3000

Press CTRL-C to stop

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
webpack built 05ca26999e06dbfe2da9 in 13788ms

Comment: Do not auto run again when change code, help me, thanks